# Why ASP.NET MVC 2 hasn't default.aspx and didn't work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Why Default.aspx missing if I created ASP.NET MVC 2 project? And why this project didn't work on IIS?

Comment: Ask a question, then answer it almost immediately....

Comment: I had a problem. I found solution and I want share that with community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default.aspx is need only for IIS6 or IIS7 (Classic Mode).

If you have problem with running project without Default.aspx in IIS, set ASP.NET to Integrated Pipeline mode.